# Unix - Finding third largest file in a folder and read first 5 lines

Tags: linux, unix

How do I find the third largest file and read first 5 lines

I tried below to get the third largest file

ls -s /file/path | head 3 | tail -1

How do I use this file name to read the first 5 lines and insert to a new file?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just forgot to capitilize `-s` and you forgot to put dash in front of the number in `head 3`

```
ls -S /file/path
```

That works to output a list of files sorted by size.

```
head -3
```

Then you need to put a dash in front of your option for `head` just like you did with `tail -1`.

To read a certain number of lines from a file you can use `head` in the same way and provide it a filename.

Comment: Thank you Maximilian, how do I transfer that file name from the first result to the second command?

Comment: Don't have to assign it to a variable ... `head -5 $(ls -S /file/path | head -3 | tail -1)`